# Running Sum with gaps in the data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query of running sum with partition. It fetches the 4 weekly running sum of the dataset with current row and 3 rows below. My problem is that the dataset has gaps and doesn't have all weeks in the data which causes my running sum to be incorrect. Can i use SQL to fill in the missing weeks so my 4 week running sum to be accurate. In the below example data for 26/10 and 2/11 is missing so my 4 week future running sum is inaccurate

Sample Data

```
Item_No Week_Starting_Monday    Cover_Weeks Four_Weeks_Cover
6-KDDDORF   20201012    3   8
6-KDDDORF   20201019    2  9
6-KDDDORF   20201109    1   12
6-KDDDORF   20201116    2   11
6-KDDDORF   20201123    4   9
6-KDDDORF   20201130    5   5
```

Desired Data

```
Item_No Week_Starting_Monday    Cover_Weeks Four_Weeks_Cover
6-KDDDORF   20201012    3   5
6-KDDDORF   20201019    2   3
6-KDDDORF   20201109    1   12
6-KDDDORF   20201116    2   11
6-KDDDORF   20201123    4   9
6-KDDDORF   20201130    5   5
```

Query

```
      SELECT t.*,
                SUM(Cover_Weeks) OVER (PARTITION BY Item_No, (seqnum - 1) / 4)  AS Four_Weeks_Cover
        FROM (SELECT t.*,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item_No ORDER BY Week_Starting_Monday) - 1 as seqnum
              FROM Table_Name t
             ) t;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff just edited with sample data and desired result. I am looking for 4 week future running sum noting the missing weeks data.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is `cross apply`:

```
SELECT t.*, t2.cover_week_4
FROM Table_Name t CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(t2.Cover_Weeks) as cover_week_4
      FROM Table_Name t2
      WHERE t2.Item_No = t.Item_No AND
            t2.Week_starting_Monday <= t.Week_starting_Monday AND
            t2.Week_starting_Monday >= DATEADD(day, -21, t.Week_starting_Monday)
     ) t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate the missing weeks this approach uses the [tally](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1) tvf fnNumbers.  All Item_No's and all weeks are cross joined together to create the complete range of possible values.  The Table_Name table is `LEFT JOIN`'ed to the complete range of possible values.  To calculate the running 4 week sum of Cover_Weeks the `SUM OVER` function specifies `ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.

data

```
drop table if exists #Table_Name;
go
create table #Table_Name(
    Item_No                 varchar(9) not null,
    Week_Starting_Monday    date not null,
    Cover_Weeks             int not null,
    Four_Weeks_Cover        int not null);
go
    
insert #Table_Name(Item_No, Week_Starting_Monday, Cover_Weeks, Four_Weeks_Cover) values
('6-KDDDORF', '20201012', 3, 8),
('6-KDDDORF', '20201019', 2, 9),
('6-KDDDORF', '20201109', 1, 12),
('6-KDDDORF', '20201116', 2, 11),
('6-KDDDORF', '20201123', 4, 9),
('6-KDDDORF', '20201130', 5, 5);
```

tally tvf

```
create function [dbo].[fnNumbers](
  @zero_or_one   bit, 
  @n             bigint)
returns table with schemabinding as return
with n(n) as (select null from (values (1),(2),(3),(4)) n(n))
select 0 n where @zero_or_one = 0
union all
select top(@n) row_number() over(order by (select null)) n
from n na, n nb, n nc, n nd, n ne, n nf, n ng, n nh,
     n ni, n nj, n nk, n nl, n nm, n np, n nq, n nr;
```

query

```
with
all_items_cte(Item_No) as (
    select distinct Item_No from #Table_Name),
wks_cte(min_wsm, max_wsm) as (
    select min(Week_Starting_Monday), max(Week_Starting_Monday)
    from #Table_Name),
all_wks_cte(wsm) as (
    select dateadd(day, fn.n*7, min_wsm)
    from wks_cte w
         cross apply dbo.fnNumbers(0, datediff(day, w.min_wsm, w.max_wsm)/7) fn),
tn_cte(Item_No, Week_Starting_Monday, Cover_Weeks, seqnum) as (
    select ai.Item_No, aw.wsm, isnull(t.Cover_Weeks, 0),
           row_number() over (partition by ai.Item_No order by aw.wsm)
    from all_items_cte ai
         cross join all_wks_cte aw 
         left join #Table_Name t on ai.Item_No=t.Item_No
                                    and aw.wsm=t.Week_Starting_Monday)
select *, sum(Cover_Weeks) over (partition by Item_No order by Week_Starting_Monday
                                 rows between 3 preceding and current row)  AS Four_Weeks_Cover
from tn_cte
order by 2;
```

output

```
Item_No     Week_Starting_Monday    Cover_Weeks seqnum  Four_Weeks_Cover
6-KDDDORF   2020-10-12              3           1       3
6-KDDDORF   2020-10-19              2           2       5
6-KDDDORF   2020-10-26              0           3       5
6-KDDDORF   2020-11-02              0           4       5
6-KDDDORF   2020-11-09              1           5       3
6-KDDDORF   2020-11-16              2           6       3
6-KDDDORF   2020-11-23              4           7       7
6-KDDDORF   2020-11-30              5           8       12
```